# Save image in db or in file structure

Tags: sql-server, database, save-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

i am curios about to know, if i should save uploaded images in the database as binarys or save in the filestructure? Maybe some examples of when i should use both scenarios.

Duplicate topic: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: I suggest searching this site - this question has been asked and answered here _many many many_ times before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends totally on what your after, but likely you want then in a DB.
If you just upload you own (like own webpage) you could do with filesystem, but this doesn''t allow for duplicate names since it (if allowed to) overwrites the original.

But well on the other hand the filesystem could be a DB itself